# CMake find_package. Package names and their conventions

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries

I'm not very experienced with CMake, I've use it in some of my projects, though. Usually when I need to include a library into my project I do it like this in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, for example:

```
find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myProject ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I've used many libraries like OpenCV, nCurses, GSL, Boost, etc. Usually I find an example online how to include a particular library into my project via CMake. Well, now I wanted to use a sound library called `libsoundio`. Here's the link https://github.com/andrewrk/libsoundio. And it seems that I can't figure out what is the name of the this library, the name that I have to pass to `find_package(<name>)` CMake function.

So the question is is there any way to get that exact package name that I have to include in my `CMakelists.txt` file? Where do these names "come from"? Are there any naming conventions that these packages are named, since the name is case sensitive?

I've tried to use names like `libsoundio`, `soundio` and similar but none of these seem to work.

Comment: CMake's documentation on this is pretty good: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html . When you build and install libsoundio, it should generate a file under `<install-path>/lib/cmake/<package-name>` called something like `<package-name>Config.cmake`. That `<package-name>` is what you use in the `find_package(...)` call. If it doesn't, you should file a bug report with them that they should generate a config file. In the meantime, you can write your own custom `Find<package-name>.cmake` file which could be found by `find_package(<package-name> ...)`

Comment: @Justin ok, so after installing it with `make install` command I only get a bunch of `.so` and `.a` files in my `/usr/local/lib` directory and it seems there are no CMake config files in there. So that means I must create my own custom cmake config file? Just to make things clear.

Comment: Yeah, if there's no CMake config, you'd write your own `Find<package>.cmake` file and put it in your project's `cmake/` folder. Writing those is not easy, though; I'm not confident writing them myself. The best solution is to get libsoundio to install a config file, but then you'd have to wait on them for it to work.

Comment: Have a look at [CMake Modules](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules), there you can see bunch of `FindXXX.cmake` files, you can take these as examples how to write a `FindXXX.cmake` file.

Comment: @kanstar yeah I see them. If I have a file `FindXXX.cmake` then package name that I have to include in `find_package(<name>)` will be that `XXX`?

Comment: @Cactus'as Yes, exatly.